# @ModelAttribute("classname") dynamic paramater binding

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, modelattribute

```
spring mvc 

 @ModelAttribute("classname"),
```

How to make the argument "**classname**" a `dynamic` one ?

Whatever comes from view can get appended there.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiation of the command object is the only place where Spring needs to know a `command` class. However, you can override it with **@ModelAttribute** annotated method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public void show(HttpServletRequest request, 
    @ModelAttribute("objectToShow") Object objectToShow) 
{
    ...
}

@ModelAttribute("objectToShow")
public Object createCommandObject() {
    return getCommandClass().newInstance();
}
```

By the way, Spring also works fine with the real `generics`:

```
public abstract class GenericController<T> {
    @RequestMapping("/edit")  
    public ModelAndView edit(@ModelAttribute("t") T t) { ... }
}

@Controller @RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController extends GenericController<Foo> { ... }
```